# Sphere model with large homology coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

Does there exists a triangulation $\Sigma$ of a sphere $S^d$ such that *any* $d$-homology generator contains a ''large'' coefficient?

Large can be specified in various ways. I have seen some spaces with "exponential" (in the input size) homology coefficients, such as connecting $k$ copies of a mapping cylinder of a degree-two map $S^d\to S^d$ and gluing $(d+1)$-discs to both ends.

Are there any restriction that something like this cannot happen, if the simplicial complex is a sphere?

(I can't come with any smart idea but non-existence would help me to prove other things  I need)

Comment: The sum of a single copy of each simplex in the triangulation generates top homology. Seems to me like the problem with your second example is that it's not a manifold in codimension 1, so doesn't have a fundamental class given by a triangulation.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, Mike! What you say looks natural, but if I assume that $|\Sigma^d|$ is only homeomorphic to $S^d$, I wasn't sure if a triangulation cannot be "wild" or so..

Comment: They can be wild, but it will still give you a fundamental class. (There are triangulations of the sphere in which the link of a vertex is not a manifold, say.)